# How to select string pattern with conditions in loop [r]

Tags: r, string, dataframe, apply, stringr

I would like some assistance please in my quest to select parts of a string in certain rows in an r dataframe. I have mocked up some dummy data below (floyd) to illustrate.

The first dataframe row has only 1 word (its a number yes, but I am treating all numbers as characters/words) for each column, but rows 2 to 4 have more than one word. I would like to select the number in each row/cell based on a position passed to it by the named vector `cool_floyd_position`.

```
# please NB need stringr installed for my solution attempt!

# some scenario data
floyd = data.frame(people = c("roger", "david", "rick", "nick"),
               spec1 = c("1", "3 5 75 101", "3 65 85", "12 2"),
               spec2 = c("45", "75 101 85 12", "45 65 8", "45 87" ),
               spec3 = c("1", "3 5 75 101", "75 98 5", "65 32"))

# tweak my data
rownames(floyd) = floyd$people
floyd$people = NULL

# ppl of interest
cool_floyd = rownames(floyd)[2:4]

# ppl string position criteria
cool_floyd_position = c(2,3,1)
names(cool_floyd_position) = c("david", "rick", "nick")

# my solution attempt
for(i in 1:length(cool_floyd))
{
select_ppl = cool_floyd[i]
string_select = cool_floyd_position[i]

floyd[row.names(floyd) == select_ppl,] = apply(floyd[row.names(floyd) == select_ppl], 1, 
                     function(x) unlist(stringr::str_split(x, " ")[string_select]))
        }
```

I am attempting to get my floyd dataframe to look like the following, where the second word is selected for all david columns, the third word for all rick columns and the first word for all nick columns (roger columns have to just remain as is)

```
my_target_df = data.frame(people = c("roger", "david", "rick", "nick"),
                      spec1 = c("1", "5", "85", "12"),
                      spec2 = c("45", "101", "8", "45" ),
                      spec3 = c("1", "5", "5", "65"))

row.names(my_target_df) = my_target_df$people
my_target_df$people = NULL
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option using `mapply`

```
library(stringr)
#convert the factor columns to character
floyd[] <- lapply(floyd, as.character)
#transpose the floyd, subset the columns, convert to data.frame
# use mapply to extract the `word` specified in the corresponding c1
#transpose and assign it back to the row in 'floyd'
floyd[names(c1),] <- t(mapply(function(x,y) word(x, y), 
        as.data.frame(t(floyd)[, names(c1)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE), c1))
floyd
#      spec1 spec2 spec3
#roger     1    45     1
#david     5   101     5
#rick     85     8     5
#nick     12    45    65
```

where

```
c1 <- cool_floyd_position #just to avoid typing
```

Comment: @Sotos thanks for the edit.  I was doing the edit at the same time :-)  Plus one for your good solution

Comment: heh...yeah I figured :) Thanks

Comment: Thnx @akrun. Much appreciated. Apologies I didn't thnx promptly - the weekend came and bit me very quickly on Friday afternoon. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try a combination of `sapply` to iterate over the data frame, and `mapply` to extract the nth `word` from each column. i.e,

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- rbind(df[1,-1], sapply(df[-1,-1], function(i) mapply(word, i, cool_floyd_position)))
rownames(df1) <- df$people
df1
#      spec1 spec2 spec3
#roger     1    45     1
#david     5   101     5
#rick     85     8     5
#nick     12    45    65
```

The only downside of this solution is that `people` are displayed as rownames rather than a single column. There are many ways to make it a column,i.e,

```
df1$people <- rownames(df1)
rownames(df1) <- NULL
df1[c(ncol(df1), 1:ncol(df1)-1)]
#  people spec1 spec2 spec3
#1  roger     1    45     1
#2  david     5   101     5
#3   rick    85     8     5
#4   nick    12    45    65
```

Comment: Hi, Thnx @Sotos. I can live with rowname issue :). I am losing the first column though when I run your solution, well, my edit of it... 'new_df = rbind(floyd[1,-1], sapply(floyd[-1,-1], function(i) mapply(stringr::word, i, cool_floyd_position)))'

Comment: yeah, it appears as a last column but you can easily move it to front. Something like `df1 <- df1[c(4, 1, 2, 3)]` should do it...or more generic `df1[c(ncol(df1), 1:ncol(df1)-1)]`

Comment: Hi @Sotos. spec1 column disapearing alltogether. Not moving to last column.

Comment: don't know...it works for me as per your example. Maybe your full data frame is differently structured? Also do `floyd[] <- lapply(floyd[], as.character)` to convert to character before running the code

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(stringi) # you have this installed if you have stringr
library(tidyverse)

pick_pos <- function(who, x, lkp) {
  if (who %in% names(lkp)) {
    map_chr(x, ~stri_split_fixed(., " ")[[1]][lkp[[who]]])
  } else { 
    x
  }
}

rownames_to_column(floyd, "people") %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(as.character)) %>% # necessary since you have factors
  group_by(people) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(pick_pos(people, ., cool_floyd_position))) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  column_to_rownames("people")
```